# repeater ASP .NET databind to navigationURL

Tags: asp.net, databinder

I'm trying to bind an ID to an already defined navigation url from a hyperlink.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='accounts_history.aspx?accountId=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'>Historiek</asp:HyperLink>
```

This is my hyperlink. The `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>` part works but using this method the hyperlink just sees it as clear text, resulting in the following link:

```
accounts_history.aspx?accountId=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id", "accounts_history.aspx?accountId={0}") %>'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx

You should place only databinding expression in property.